# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar los valores nulos de una columna específica en un dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Tengo un DataFrame con algunas columnas que tienen valores nulos, y para cada columna quiero sustituirlos con valores específicos. He usado:

```
df['variable1'].fillna('sustituto', inplace = True)
```

pero al correr el notebook obtengo el error:

> Column' object is not callable

Comment: SunoFer ¿El dataframe es de Pandas? ¿`variable1` es el nombre de una columna? El código en este supuesto es totalmente correcto, algo más está pasando. Intenta mostrar más información o un [mcve] para poder reproducir el problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Las únicas operaciones que he hecho en el notebook fueron cargar un csv como dataframe df = sqlContext.read.csv(testcsv, header = True).drop('_c0') y borrarle una columna que no me servía, y quise sustituir os nulos de una de sus columnas (variable1) pero no me lo permitío. Al final lo que requiero es que en el df que tengo cargado se sustituyan los nulos de cada columna con valores específicos

Comment: SunoFer si no me equivoco eso es Spark (pySpark) y no Pandas. ¿Puedes confirmarlo? ipython no es mas que un shell interactivo y dataframe es un concepto general presente en multiples librerias. Es importante que digas siempre que librerías estas usando. Si es spark la sintaxis no es esa, eso es para Pandas.

Comment: sí es pyspark. Estoy usando las librerías: pyspark, pandas, numpy, pyspark.sql.types, pyspark.sql.functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis que estas usando es propia de Pandas, en Spark (pySpark) la sintaxis correcta de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) para substituir valores nulos en distintas columnas es:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----+------+-------+
| Id  |  Edad| Nombre|
+-----+------+-------+
|    1|    20|   null|
|    2|    18|    Ana|
| null|    45|  Pedro|
|   10|    34|  Laura|
+-----+------+-------+
```

Podemos hacer:

```
>>> df.na.fill({'Id': -1, 'Nombre': 'Desconocido'}).show()
+-----+-----+------------+
| Id  | Edad|      Nombre|
+-----+-----+------------+
|    1|   20| Desconocido|
|    2|   18|         Ana|
|   -1|   45|       Pedro|
|   10|   34|       Laura|
+-----+-----+------------+
```

O usar:

```
>>> df.fillna({'Id': -1, 'Nombre': 'Desconocido'}).show()
```

Se usa un diccionario en el que la clave es la columna y el valor de esa clave el nuevo valor del null substituido.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya lo he probado y funciona justo como dices. ¿Hay algo que me recomiendes para seguir aprendiendo pyspark ?